# org.openqa.selenium.support.locators does not exist

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea

I have selenium 4 installed but I can't find the repository of locator nor a jar to add:

```
java: package org.openqa.selenium.support.locators does not exist
```

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have version `4.0.0-alpha-3` or newer.

See [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-support) in Maven.

If you ensure you have the following core Java dependency in your POM (assuming you are using Maven!) then you will automatically get the `selenium-support` JAR as well:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-alpha-6</version>
</dependency>
```

This uses `4.0.0-alpha-6` - which is the currently the latest.

Answer (score 0):

You also need `selenium-support`, as in

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```